# cant compile in Qt said both error 1 and error 2

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-errors

I was writing a program for my physics project, and I want to make a dialog to play a few notes' recording from my abs pipe instrument, it compiled and ran perfectly. But when i closed the software, and tried to reopen and make a new project, it just won't compile and came with these errors.
Here's the compile output, i don't know why and i tried the solutions from other similar solved questions, but they don't work...Please help me, this project is due tomorrow and i just started Qt today

> 19:51:24: Running steps for project acoustic...
>   19:51:24: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
>   19:51:24: Starting: "G:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe"
>       G:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile.Debug
>       cl -c -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -Zc:strictStrings -Zc:throwingNew -Zi -MDd -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -w44996 -w44456 -w44457 -w44458 -wd4577 -EHsc /Fddebug\acoustic.pdb -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_MULTIMEDIA_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I..\acoustic -I. -IG:\Qt\5.7\msvc2015_64\include -IG:\Qt\5.7\msvc2015_64\include\QtMultimedia -IG:\Qt\5.7\msvc2015_64\include\QtWidgets -IG:\Qt\5.7\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui -IG:\Qt\5.7\msvc2015_64\include\QtANGLE -IG:\Qt\5.7\msvc2015_64\include\QtNetwork -IG:\Qt\5.7\msvc2015_64\include\QtCore -Idebug -I. -IG:\Qt\5.7\msvc2015_64\mkspecs\win32-msvc2015 -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\gavin\AppData\Local\Temp\main.obj.2892.0.jom
>   'cl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>   jom: C:\Users\gavin\Desktop\acoustic application\build-acoustic-Desktop_Qt_5_7_0_MSVC2015_64bit-Debug\Makefile.Debug [debug\main.obj] Error 1
>       cl -c -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -Zc:strictStrings -Zc:throwingNew -Zi -MDd -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -w44996 -w44456 -w44457 -w44458 -wd4577 -EHsc /Fddebug\acoustic.pdb -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_MULTIMEDIA_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I..\acoustic -I. -IG:\Qt\5.7\msvc2015_64\include -IG:\Qt\5.7\msvc2015_64\include\QtMultimedia -IG:\Qt\5.7\msvc2015_64\include\QtWidgets -IG:\Qt\5.7\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui -IG:\Qt\5.7\msvc2015_64\include\QtANGLE -IG:\Qt\5.7\msvc2015_64\include\QtNetwork -IG:\Qt\5.7\msvc2015_64\include\QtCore -Idebug -I. -IG:\Qt\5.7\msvc2015_64\mkspecs\win32-msvc2015 -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\gavin\AppData\Local\Temp\dialog.obj.2892.31.jom
>   'cl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>   jom: C:\Users\gavin\Desktop\acoustic application\build-acoustic-Desktop_Qt_5_7_0_MSVC2015_64bit-Debug\Makefile.Debug [debug\dialog.obj] Error 1
>   jom: C:\Users\gavin\Desktop\acoustic application\build-acoustic-Desktop_Qt_5_7_0_MSVC2015_64bit-Debug\Makefile [debug] Error 2 
>   19:51:25: The process "G:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" exited with code 2.
>   Error while building/deploying project acoustic (kit: Desktop Qt 5.7.0 MSVC2015_64bit)
>   When executing step "Make"
>   19:51:25: Elapsed time: 00:00.

Comment: You are probably getting downvoted because you did not post an MCVE: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @KeithM I don't really know where's the error so I just put all the log in case i missed something important, i can't really understand the log

Comment: Might want to start the project earlier next time ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to review your setup:

> 'cl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

This means that the build process can't find the program `cl.exe`.
You may have to tell the build process where the program is or alter your path so that the operating system can find it.

Comment: How do I do that? I have a patch file like this:                                          `call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\cl.exe"  
"G:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\qtcreator" `